# Pattern ideas for multi-step pages in Meteor.js

Tags: meteor

I'm creating a multi-step process (4 steps to be exact) that is initiated from a link on the home page. For example I am clicking a link that says "Create a Job Post" and that takes me to step 1 of creating that post. The way I'm handling it with FlowRouter is creating 4 separate routes like this "/job/create/step-1", "job/create/step2", etc.

Then I create 4 templates one for each step of the process and then I linked them together using "Back" and "Continue" buttons to move forward or backwards in the steps process in case the user needs to edit and all that good stuff.

The way i'm approaching it works, and i'm not aware of any pitfalls of doing it this way if any; but it does seem like there's a cleaner more logical way to do this.

I was wondering if anyone had any patterns to offer, or advice on how something like this could be handled in meteor. I suppose you could compare it to how some blogs have a "Next" and "Previous" button to grab the previous post record and to grab the next post record without knowing what those posts are. I like the dynamic way of doing this, but I also should reason with myself that in this particular use case I only have 4 steps and all the pages are known and won't change.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks to anyone that takes the time. I'm looking more for ideas and existing patterns than anything else, but if you have some code to share in making your point that's cool too.

Comment: You should also think about how you're going to handle the data that is 1) being inserted at each step of the form and 2) being displayed when a user goes back to a previous step of the form.

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny um No I haven't, guess I should I was hoping FlowRouter could help me with that, but haven't gotten that far yet. I'd love to just have the routes reflect the steps and have my steps counter highlight the step they are on, but yeah you make a good point on that part as well. Have you used meteor to handle something like this? Thanks.

Comment: @MARS have you ever solved this? I am facing a similar scenario, and am not sure how to proceed. Separate routes do not seem like the best solution to my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32520801/routing-for-multi-step-process