# Routing for multi step process

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Edit: Shortened and clarified the problem.

What's the most practical way to achieve the following in my Meteor app using Iron Router:

- Condition A - show template A
- Condition B - show template B
- otherwise - show template C

for a single URL, so that a user cannot directly enter "/url-a" or "/url-b" or "url-c" to select the view/template explicitly.

Comment: Ah, SO at its best. Downvotes and close requests without comments...

Comment: Edit: Shortened and clarified the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Given the limited information you've provided, I can't think of anything shorter than the following logic in your route:

```
if ( A ) this.render('templateA');
else if ( B ) this.render('templateB');
else this.render('templateC');
```

This assumes that you have a route with a layout and you're rendering a template into that layout.

But given this answer is so trivial I suspect you're asking a different question altogether.

Comment: My initial question (before the edit) was more generic/gave more context: If I have a process across multiple pages that I want the user to follow in a certain order, how should I implement this? After thinking about it, editing the question and reading your solution, I think the answer should be: One route, multiple templates, chosen at runtime depending on the current step of the workflow. Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: But when I am trying to progress from one step (form) to the next, sending the router to the same URL does not seem to render the next template:

Template.step1.events({
    'submit form': function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        Meteor.call("myMethod", event.target.name.value, event.target.email.value);
        Router.go('processRoute');
    }
});

Comment: Using  Meteor._reload.reload(); fixes the render update issue - still, it seems a bit ... un-meteorish..?

Comment: ok that's a lot clearer. I'll come back and write a meteoric answer when I have some time.